# Nvidia 430 driver broke again?

Tags: nvidia

I have Lenovo legion Y540 with Nvidia RTX 2060 graphics card.

Yesterday I installed updates, along with it came Nvidia driver update. Now i'm unable to boot. For booting, now I have to always boot from recovery mode.

Please help.

Comment: Check under Software & Updates. Go to Additional Drivers, try using any of the optional drivers listed.

Comment: @Crabtree thank your for the quick response. It worked! Somehow my driver got changed to nouveau after the update. Reverting back to 430 worked!

Comment: Awesome!!! Super glad to be of help. Good luck continuing on.

Comment: @Crabtree Can you please write an answer? I want to give you some credits if I can with 1 contribution. :)

Comment: Thanks Dushyant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Software & Updates. Go to Additional Drivers, change the driver used.